# How to use an Object in Windows Service application in C#

Tags: c#, static, windows-services, static-methods, keyboard-hook

I am developing a keyboard capturing service in C#. The program must be able to capture keys and save key codes to specified file in program. I used CodeProject source code for develop my application. I am not familiar with C#.

I used this [CodeProject](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B53F0wBGnYhdMmFqaTVsbzMtVjA/view?usp=sharing) source code (this is only the class that I used for capture keyboard) as a class of my service.

This is the coding of windows service program.

```
static void gkh_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("Up\t"+e.KeyCode.ToString());
        fs.Write(info,0,info.Length);
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

And:

```
static void gkh_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("Up\t"+e.KeyCode.ToString());
        fs.Write(info,0,info.Length);
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Above two methods are not not working.

But, I have added it in to the `main()` method like this.

```
gkh.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyDown);
gkh.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyUp);
```

My question is why this program unable to capture keyboard key events?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

using Utilities;

namespace WindowsService
{
    class WindowsService : ServiceBase
    {
      public WindowsService()
      {
        this.ServiceName = "My Windows Service";
      }

      static FileStream fs  = File.Open("C:/Users/User/Desktop/keyLog.txt",FileMode.Append,FileAccess.Write,FileShare.None);

      static void Main()
      {
        globalKeyboardHook gkh = new globalKeyboardHook();

        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.A);


        gkh.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyDown);
        gkh.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyUp);

        Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("This is some text in the file for test.");
        fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);

        ServiceBase.Run(new WindowsService());
      }

      static void gkh_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
      {
        Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("Up\t"+e.KeyCode.ToString());
        fs.Write(info,0,info.Length);
        e.Handled = true;
      }

      static void gkh_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
      {
        Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("Down\t"+e.KeyCode.ToString());
        fs.Write(info,0,info.Length);
        e.Handled = true;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Source codes:
Keyboard Hook program:http://goo.gl/Np3EQR  and Basic Windows Service program:http://goo.gl/qPud5j

Comment: I guess because windows service runs under SYSTEM user and is not able to get input from keyboard.

Comment: Put your program on a terminal server with 10 people connected, which keybord do you get? Now you might see the problem, your program can't run as a service.